# ImportError: No module named 'app.settings.ci'; 'app.settings' is not a package

Tags: python, django

I have got an error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'app.settings.ci'; 'app.settings' is not a package.
```

I want to install CircleCI 2.0 into Django application. The traceback says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/rf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/rf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 317, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/rf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/rf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/rf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/rf/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'analytics_api.settings.ci'; 'analytics_api.settings' is not a package
```

I run the command `python manage.py makemigrations --settings app.settings.ci` when the error happens. I think this command is necessary to install  CircleCI 2.0, but is it wrong? How can I fix this? What is wrong with my code?

In settings.py I wrote

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app',
    'data',
    'user',
]
```

Comment: Please show `INSTALLED_APPS` from your `settings.py`.

Comment: @cezar I added INSTALLED_APPS in my question

Comment: Why are you doing `--settings app.settings.ci`. What is this different settings file you are trying to use?

Comment: @Alasdair I wanna make setting file for CircleCI

Comment: Why does CircleCI need a separate settings file (I haven't used it before). What's the difference between your regular settings file and this one? Why do you think you need to run `makemigrations` with this settings file?

Answer (score 2):

To have multiple settings files, you need to create a Python module and use it.

```
/app
|-- settings
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- base.py <--- the current setting.py file
|   |-- ci.py
```

## ci.py

```
from .base import *

# override settings here
```

**Note:**

You can set environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to use the default settings.